# How to re-load route child-components after URL segment changed?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having routes which are the same for different projects. So everything shown depends just on `:projectId`:

```
  {path: 'projects/:projecteId', children: [
    {path: 'info', component: InfoComponent},
    {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},

  ], canActivate: [ProjectGuard]},

  // Other routes ..
  {path: 'account', component: AccountComponent]
```

In my toolbar I am having an option to select a project - similar to what you can do in the GAE console:

[image]

I would like to know how I can make a change in `projectId` detectable and update all affected components.

As you can see I have a `ProjectGuard` - the idea would be to have a guard that observes an object provided by  a `ProjectService` and applies changes whenever the selection changes. However, I am not sure if this is a viable solution and whether there is a better, more Angular-ish way, to do something like that.

Do I really need such a guard here?

Comment: Which component do you load for `projects/:projecteId` path?

Comment: If you navigate to a different project, the ActivatedRoutes will emit new params, and you can thus observe the params change from your components. Not sure if that's what you're asking. You can also tweak the RouteReuseStrategy: https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy#shouldReuseRoute

Answer (score 0):

In the component that you'll load for `path: 'projects/:projecteId'`, you can inject the `ActivatedRoute` and listen to `params` Observable on it.

The change in `params` will run your code:

Let's say that you open a `ProjectComponent`, you can do something like:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})
export class ProjectComponent  {
  projectId;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.projectId = params['projecteId'];
      // Here you'll always get notified when `projecteId` changes.
      // You can do the needful from here.
    });
  }

}
```

**Update:**

In case of a [**`CanActivate`**](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard, inside the [**`canActivate`**](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#canActivate) you can use the [**`ActivatedRouteSnapshot`**](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot). That also has a `params` on it which is an Object but with the updated `params`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // Here the `next.params.projectId` will always give you updated projectId
    ...
  }
}
```

You can watch for `params.projectId` and then also use some sort of a service that would store the previous value of the `projectId`. This you could use to compare with the current value of `projectId` to check if the Project was actually changed from the dropdown. You can then inject that service as a dependency in the ProjectGuard and you'll be good to go.

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvideo.guard.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Well, I do not have a `ProjectComponent` at this point. I went with a guard as you can take from my question. I don't think I need an entire component for this.

Comment: Inside the guard `params` is always an empty dictionary (`{}`) O_o

Comment: Well in that case, since you're using it in a `CanActivate` guard, you'll get the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` as the first arg. to the `canActivate` method. Even that has params on it that you can subscribe to, to get the value. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: `params` is not an observable though :/

Comment: Oh and actually - the whole subscribing thing will nevere work since the route will nevere change until I updated it. The whole point is to detect a condition, "user changed project" and *then* navigate to another route. I'm afraid you misunderstood what I am looking for.

Comment: @StefanFalk. could you please give the updated solution a try? I still think using a ProjectComponent and the `ActivatedRoute` in it would have been a bit more convenient.